# Post-hoc for 2x2 mixed design ANOVA using SPSS

Tags: anova, spss, post-hoc

I am analysing an experiment run with 20 participants using a $2\times 2$ mixed design ANOVA. The experiment has

- one within subjects variable *A* with two levels (*a1*, *a2*)
- one between subjects variable *B* with two levels (*b1*, *b2*)

The following are the results of the ANOVA analysis:

> B   F(1,18) = 5,84 p<0,026493 SS=1,44 MSe=0,25
>
> A   F(1,18) = 11,1 p<0,003734 SS=1,25 MSe=0,11
>
> B*A F(1,18) = 7,16 p<0,015412 SS=0,81 MSe=0,11

Is there any reason to run post-hoc test in this context? SPSS complains about variables having less than 3 levels and, for this reason, doesn't allow me to run Post-hoc tests.

**Question**
Is it possible to run bonferroni post-hoc test in this kind of scenario? If not, why? If yes, how to do it in SPSS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no use for a post hoc test here.  What could you possibly find in a post hoc that isn't obvious from the ANOVA?  There's a main effect of A and a main effect of B and an interaction.

Some people do them to do something like test whether A1B1 - A1B2 is significant while A2B1 - A2B2 is not.  They find that result and report it as important but it's meaningless because it tells you *less* than the interaction already told you.  Significant and not-significant is not a test of differences between conditions dependent upon the level of the other condition.  The interaction already was that test.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as posted by the OP, but I am confused as to how I can clearly explain the nature of the 2 by 2 interaction without doing post hoc tests. For example, if the change in group A between time 1 and time 2 is quite different than the change in group B between time 1 and time 2, how can they be statistically shown without post hoc tests?

Comment: @pdhami what you just described is exactly what the interaction test is. You could say, "The change in group A is smaller (or larger, or in the opposite direction or whatever the case may be) than group B as evidenced by the interaction, F(1, 28) = ... " No additional test between any individual pair of means can show that.

Answer (score -2):

The interaction test can be significant, whereas the post hocs are not, especially if it's a cross-over pattern.  That's why they need to be conducted.

Comment: Which post hoc test would you conduct? There are only two levels. Any statistically significant result would demonstrate difference between the two levels.

Comment: In the light of the information in the other answer (which you're free to disagree with, if you explain why), can you expand your answer to explain the apparent discrepancy?

Comment: I don't even see how this answers the question...